# How can I delete ursina entity which I saved in dictionary?

Tags: python, minecraft, ursina

I"m creating minecraft, and I ruin into problem where I save my block into a "blocks_dictionary", but when I try to destroy the block nothing is hapening.

Here's my code:

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
import random

app = Ursina()

player = FirstPersonController()  # Creating player
player.y = 25

blocks_dictionary = {}  # Dictionary for storing blocks

def input(key):
    if key == 'm':
        mine_block(random.randint(1,5), random.randint(1,5), random.randint(1,5))

def mine_block(x,y,z):
    destroy(blocks_dictionary.get((x,y,z)))

def generate_chunk(x, y, z):
    chunk = Entity(collider='box', model=None)  # Making chunk
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            for u in range(5):
                generate_block(x + i, y + u, z + j, chunk)  # Creating block

    chunk.combine(auto_destroy=False)  # Generating chunk
    chunk.collider = 'mesh'  # Changing collider
    chunk.texture = 'grass.png'  # Adding texture

def generate_block(x, y, z, parent):
    # Creating block
    block = Entity(position=(x, y, z), model='block.obj', texture='grass.png')
    block.parent = parent  # Linking block to a chunk
    blocks_dictionary[x, y, z] = block  # Storing block in the blocks dictionary

generate_chunk(0,0,0)

sky = Sky()  # Creating sky

app.run()
```

I tried to save my block into list, but I got the same result. Exatcly the same thing with a tuple.

Comment: After you combine the chunk, the entity wouldn't destroy.

Comment: So, what I need to do instead of combining terrain?

Comment: You can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liaHR64Wqag) tutorial, this might help you